# How to import Google map into my application

Tags: android

I want to create a tourist guide android application that will show major locations in a certain cities. Pls help me with bany usefull information on this project.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple import by using `GoogleMapActivity`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Am interested in just showing a certain region that will serve as a tourist guide to some particular places in the city

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the link, it will provide all necessary information..
https://developer.android.com/training/maps/index.html

You will require google map API key:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

Answer (score 0):

First you have to register your application in `Google Console`. Then you have to Enable the service you want to use i.e. `MAP API` from `Google Console`.

This is the link it may be helpful for you just check it follow the steps. [Google MAP](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start)

I suggest you to use [SmartLocation](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib) library to handle all MAP related work. It provides you `GeoCoding`, `ReverseGeo` and much more.

To use it just you have to import in your `Gradle` file and register your `activity` or `fragment`.

```
compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.11'
```

**Starting**

```
SmartLocation.with(context).location()
    .start(new OnLocationUpdatedListener() { ... });
```

**Stopping**

```
SmartLocation.with(context).location().stop();
```

Just try this. Hope it helps you.